# How does RESULT_RESCHEDULE works in GCMNetworkManager?

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

At first I thinked, that `RESULT_RESCHEDULE` is the same, as `RESULT_SUCCESS` but for periodic task.

Then I read [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager.html#RESULT_RESCHEDULE), and it says

> RESULT_RESCHEDULE Indicates a task has failed to execute, and must be retried with back-off.

I'm confused, what does it means? What is "back-off" in current context?

Comment: https://github.com/filipproch/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @lingareddyk thanks, that's what I needed